# Why file sharing connection to other 10.9 machine via guest account always fail?

Tags: macos, networking, permissions, file-sharing, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to allow guest access to ~/Public and Dropbox folders in the standard fashion on my iMac but any guest connection automatically fails. Connecting as Registered user or by Apple Id works as expected but the guest account always fails with "Access to your account of the server has been denied". I checked permissions on the Volume, the home folder, and the public folder and all have read access for 'Everyone'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have guest access enabled in System Preferences -> Users & Groups pane -> Guest account -> Allow guests to connect to shared folders?

Comment: Well what do ya know. Never knew about that option and puzzled as to how it may have been turned off.